# Updating fontsize with highcharts using zoomtype

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a column chart in Highcharts with a big number of columns so the columns are very small.
That's fine but I want to do zoom.
So I used zoomtype: 'x' and it work well.

The problem is that I want to make the font bigger on the xAxis when they are selected.
I tried by doing this:

```
chart: {
            type: 'column',
            zoomType: 'x',
            events: {
                redraw: function(event) {
                    if(this.xAxis[0].tickPositions.length>80){
                        this.xAxis[0].options.labels.style.fontSize = 1;
                    }else{
                        this.xAxis[0].options.labels.style.fontSize = 20;
                        console.log(this.xAxis[0].options.labels.style.fontSize);                  
                    }

                }

            }
        }
```

When I check the console the value of this.xAxis[0].options.labels.style.fontSize is updated to 20.
This code works only when I press the Reset zoom button.
So my question is how can I update the chart when the event is triggered so it takes the same effects as if I use the Reset zoom button?

Or how can I make changes in the font when I make zoom and when reseting the zoom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch [afterSetExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes) event and then [axis.update()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.update) with new styles for bales.

```
events:{
            afterSetExtremes:function(){
                this.update({
                    labels:{
                        style:{
                            fontSize:20
                        } 
                    }
                });
            }
 }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/m180dxsu/

Comment: It works perfect!! I lose a lot of time trying other stuff that did not work. Thank you very much.